# make servlet filter applicable for all web applications

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, servlet-filters

I am developing a web application using JSP & Servlets.

I have developed a `servlet filter` for `Login` purpose. Which checks whether user is logged in or not, if user is logged in then it allows access to the requested resource, else it redirects request to the `Login page`. And it works perfectly.

**Filter**

```
public class MyFilter implements Filter
{
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException 
    {
        //code here
    }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.myfilter.MyFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>PARAM_NAME_HERE</param-name>
        <param-value>PARAM_VALUES_HERE</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Now I have deployed this application named `Login` on `Tomcat 7`. This `servlet filter` works perfectly for the resources (JSPs, Servltes, .css, .js) in this web application.

So now in `Tomcat` there are other web applications like `Profiles`, `Distribution` etc. So now what I want is apply the `Filter` in `Login` application *Applicable* for all other applications deployed in the `Tomcat`. Means every request to other application resources should go through the `Filter` which I have developed.

So any suggestions will be appreciated!

**Edit1**

I dont want to put package which contains `Filter` in other applications.  Because in Tomcat server there are more than 10 applications are deployed, and some more are going to be deployed. So suppose if I put the package which contains `Filter` in all other applications and do servlet mapping , but if some days after I want to make some changes in the Filter then I will need to make changes in all applications, and redeploying them will be needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your `<filter>` and `<filter-mapping>` definition inside `$CATALINA_HOME/conf/web.xml`

These definitions are shared by all you web applications.

You will have to package all your login related logic in a jar and put it under `$CATALINA_HOME\lib` so it will be accessible to all of your web applications.

Comment: What is the way to do the same in weblogic and OHS?

Answer (score 1):

Add this your code into the web.xml of other two applications.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.myfilter.MyFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>PARAM_NAME_HERE</param-name>
        <param-value>PARAM_VALUES_HERE</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

**Filter**

```
public class MyFilter implements Filter
{
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException 
    {
        //code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it doesn't work, it gives exception while starting Tomcat Server `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.myfilter.MyFilter` , My package which contains Filter is in `Login` Application.

Comment: @Bhushan Ya it will give that error because you are not adding this package com.myfilter.Myfilter into your other two application . Just ass them and try.

Comment: yes, I know if add this package in those application then it will work perfectly, but My question is that how should I make the `Filter` which is in `Login` application `Applicable` to the all other applications deployed in tomcat

Comment: @Bhushan what is the need of doing like that.

Comment: @Bhushan No point in doing that and according to me its not possible.

Comment: I need this because in `Tomcat` server there are more than 10 applications are deployed, and some more are going to be deployed. So suppose if I put this package in other applications, and some days after I want to make some changes in the Filter then I will need to make changes in all application, and redeploying them will be needed.

Comment: @Bhushan +1 for this question bhushan.Let me think and search...... I will get back here